# Prime number checking function not working on a test case

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to coding but I'm having an issue with my code. The code seems to work with every test number and I can tell why.

```py
num1 = int(input('Please enter a positive integer: '))

def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1 :
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    for n in range(3,x-1,2):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False

    return True

print(is_prime(num1))
```

`4` is returning a `True` value when it should be `False`.

Answer (score 2):

This is your culprit:

```py
for n in range(3,x-1,2):
    if x % n == 0:
        return False

return True
```

Your step term in `range` is 2 starting at 3, so 4 doesn't get tested. Because it isn't tested, your function just returns `True`.

You can fix this naively by adding another `elif` checking input mod 2 before your range.

```py
def is_prime(x):
    if x <= 1 :
        return False
    elif x == 2:
        return True
    elif x % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for n in range(3,x-1,2):
        if x % n == 0:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: This may fix the problem, but doesn't it give you a feeling that it's a bit more complicated than it needs to be? I'm pretty sure there is an easy way to do it without so many special cases.

Comment: @MichaelGeary I definitely agree with you. I've only been actively learning python for the past couple of weeks so I'm sure with practice I can definitely refine the code.

Comment: Thank you all for your help I very much appreciate it.